# Migrating models to a single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, migration, single-table-inheritance

Right now I have two models, a landlord review model and a housing review model. I realized that there are many similarities between these classes and it would have made sense to use inheritance with a review super class. Unfortunately, the application is already in production. My question is how could I go about migrating these models to use an inheritance relationship and what kind of impact would there be?

Comment: What are the similitudes / differences between LandlordReview and HousingReview models? Maybe you could have a generic Review model with a polymorphic relation to the reviewed_object (reviewed_object_id, reviewed_object_type)

Comment: aren't you using version controlling? if you are, then just create a new branch and do your R&D.

Comment: @MrYoshiji So there are some attributes and methods they both share so at the moment I have some duplication

Comment: @HasanIqbalAnik Yeah, I am using version control, I guess my question was for more of a high level what kind of impact would be made in terms of the database.